# cant store session variable into database

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have in seassion stored variable. I want to insert session variable and other informations filled through form into table. I got message that it was created but nothing shows in table.

I want to take session variable and store it into "username"
i tried $username=$r['username']; but doesnt work.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['user']==''){
        header("Location:login.php");
    }else{
        $dbh=new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydb;host=127.0.0.1', 'myusername', 'mypassword');


    $sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?");
    $sql->execute(array($_SESSION['user']));
    while($r=$sql->fetch()){

    $username=$r['username'];  <-im not sure if this is correct.
    $ime=$_POST['ime'];
    $priimek=$_POST['priimek'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $izob=$_POST['izob'];
    $izk=$_POST['izk'];
    $prib=$_POST['prib'];
    $opis=$_POST['opis'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO profil (ime, priimek, email, izob, izk, prib, opis) VALUES( `username`,`ime` , `priimek ` , `email` , `izob` , `izk` , `prib` , `opis`)";

        try {
            $dbh->exec($sql);
            echo " created successfully";
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    $conn = null;
}
?>

CREATE TABLE profil(
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        username VARCHAR(10),
        ime VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        priimek VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(20),
        izob VARCHAR(20),
        izk VARCHAR(10),
        prib VARCHAR(10),
        opis VARCHAR(100),
);
```

thanks for help

Comment: `print_r($r)`, (On the line above where you think the issue is, and paste the results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys thnx for help i found soulution. 
this line was wrong:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO test (`column`) VALUES(  '$value1' '$value2)";
```

Tnx guys

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

First, you only specified 7 column names in the insert list, but you gave 8 values.  Most importantly, the column name you failed to specify was the `username` column, which is what you are asking about.  Second, you should be using the actual PHP variables in the insert, not the column names escaped in backticks.  Try the following:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO profil (username, ime, priimek, email, izob, izk, prib, opis) ";
$sql = $sql . "VALUES(".$username.", ".$ime.", ".$priimek$.", ".$email.", ".$izob.", ".$izk.", ".$prib.", ".$opis.")";
```

Comment: I tried but still doesnt work. I tought it might be problem with variable username but i can echo it ok.still nothing shown in db

Answer (score 0):

remove `username` to your **values** and add backticks to **insert**.

it should be like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO profil (`ime`, `priimek`, `email`, `izob`, `izk`, ``prib, `opis`) VALUES(`ime` , `priimek ` , `email` , `izob` , `izk` , `prib` , `opis`)";
```

Comment: i need username its essential. $username=$r['username']; echo "$username"; it prints the variable. now i need to store it in table